# "Chaining" two controllers?

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc

A REST-API I am developing allows access to various kinds of user data.

Users can be identified via their Id, their email or their username. A user then has a couple of other data such as orders etc.

Now I am planning to expose the following endpoints:

- /rest/user/byemail/test@example.org/profile
- /rest/user/byemail/test@example.org/orders
- /rest/user/byemail/test@example.org/address
- /rest/user/byid/123456/profile
- /rest/user/byid/123456/orders
- /rest/user/byid/123456/address
- /rest/user/byusername/test/profile
- /rest/user/byusername/test/orders
- /rest/user/byusername/test/address

As you can see, the URL always consists of two "parts": One for identifying the user and the other one for identifying the resource.

It would be great if I could now avoid writing 9 different methods in my controller (as there might be other types of information in the future).

Is it somehow possible to write one `UserController` which is then returned and parametrized by the `MainController`?

```
public class UserController {
   @RequestMapping("/profile")
   public ModelAndView profile(User user) {
      //...
   }
   @RequestMapping("/orders")
   public ModelAndView profile(User user) {
      //...
   }
   @RequestMapping("/address")
   public ModelAndView profile(User user) {
      //...
   }
}

@RequestMapping("/rest/user")
public class MainController {
   @RequestMapping("byemail/{email}")
   public ??? byEmail(@PathVariable String email) {
       User user = //Find user by email
       //???
   }
   @RequestMapping("byusername/{username}")
   public ??? byUserName(@PathVariable String username) {
       User user = //Find user by username
       //???
   }
   @RequestMapping("byid/{id}")
   public ??? byId(@PathVariable String id) {
       User user = //Find user by id
       //???
   }
}
```

Or is it maybe possible to solve this via some kind of routing?
However, it would be important to "split" the URL and use one half to find the correct user which will then be available as a parameter when parsing the second half.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just one controller with these request mappings?

```
@RequestMapping("/rest/user")
public class UserController {

   @RequestMapping("{keyType}/{key}/orders")
   public ModelAndView orders(@PathVariable String keyType, @PathVariable String key) {
       User u = findUser(keyType, key);
       // ...
   }

   @RequestMapping("{keyType}/{key}/profile")
   public ModelAndView profile(@PathVariable String keyType, @PathVariable String key) {

       User u = findUser(keyType, key);
       // ...
   }

   @RequestMapping("{keyType}/{key}/address")
   public ModelAndView address(@PathVariable String keyType, @PathVariable String key) {
       User u = findUser(keyType, key);
       // ...
   }

   private User findUser(String keyType, String key) {
       // ...
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - definitely better than multiple methods, but still not optimal as it introduces more complexity (more parameters + the logic in findUser).

Comment: Well, but you would get rid of one controller with three methods. But I guess complexity is in the eye of the beholder :-)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Spring Data REST](http://www.springsource.org/spring-data/rest).

This API exposes a `SimpleJpaRespository` to the web, accessible via RESTful paths.